# I'm working on creating a function skeleton to automate data storage in localStorage but I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage, dom-events

First, I have a main.js file, that contains 2 functions to export :

```
export function call_a_change_listener() {
    input_to_store.addEventListener('change', func_to_call);
}
```

and

```
export function add_to_local_storage(local_place_name, the_input) {
    let myVar;
    if (localStorage.getItem(local_place_name) === null) {
        myVar = [];
    } else {
        myVar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(local_place_name));
    }
    myVar.push(the_input.value);
    localStorage.setItem(local_place_name, JSON.stringify(myVar));
    console.log(the_input.value)
}
```

I import those functions into another js file (stats.js), in order to use them :

```
import {add_to_local_storage, call_a_change_listener} from './main.js'
```

Then I use them like that :

```
let the_input_tag = document.getElementById("the_input");

call_a_change_listener(the_input_tag, add_to_local_storage('the_key_name', the_input_tag));
```

when I did that, I wrote something into the input, and it only returns [""] into the localStorage "**the_key_name**" corresponding row and so on...

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: the good function is : export function call_a_change_listener(input_to_store, func_to_call) {
    input_to_store.addEventListener('change', func_to_call);
}

Comment: `call_a_change_listener` should look something like this... `input_to_store.addEventListener('change', () => func_to_call(input_to_store, value));`

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try it